# Why after update store, component doesn't change (React-Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I have a `component`, that doesn't change data after updated `store`

```js
class RenderComments extends Component {

  commentsParse() {
    return this.props.comments.map((comment) => {

      if (comment.hasComments === true) {

        return (
          <div key={comment.id}>
            <CommentItem  data={comment} />        
          </div>
        ) // return
      } 
    }); // this.props.comments.map()
  } // commentParse

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.commentsParse() }
      </div>
    ) // return
  } // render
} // RenderComments

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    comments: state
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RenderComments);
```

`dispatcher`

```js
class AddComment extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      comment: ''
    }
  }

  addNewComment() {
    this.props.addNewComment(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <div className="comment-entry">
          <div className="form-group">
            <textarea
              onChange={event => this.setState({comment: event.target.value})}
            >
            </textarea>
          </div>
          <div className="comment-entry-footer">
            <button
              onClick={() => this.addNewComment()}
            >
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    ) // return
  } // render
} // AddComment

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    comment: state
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({addNewComment}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddComment);
```

this is my `reducer`

```js
import { ADD_COMMENT } from './../constants';

let allUserComments = [/* Array with 4 objects */]

const createNewComment = (action) => {
      let d = new Date();
  let n = d.toLocaleTimeString();

  let newComment = {
    id: Math.random(),
    rating: 0,
    name: 'MyNick',
    thumbnail: 'icon.50x50.png',
    time: n,
    comment: action.text.comment,
    replyTo: null,
    replyToUser: null,
    hasComments: false
  }

  allUserComments.push(newComment);
  return allUserComments;
}

export default (state = allUserComments, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_COMMENT:
      allUserComments = createNewComment(action);
      return allUserComments;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

In first launch application, my `component` shows 4 objects i.e `state` that return `reducer`, but after `action`, `component` doesn't re-render, it's continuing shows 4 object instead 5. Why `component` doesn't update?

Comment: Show the content of `createNewComment `.

Comment: Can we see the code that dispatches ADD_COMMENT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reducer is *very* wrong, on several levels.  It's not following the requirement of updating data immutably.

First, you shouldn't be maintaining a separate `allUserComments` array outside the reducer function.

Second, you shouldn't be using `.push()` to mutate an array - you would want to use `.concat()` to return a new array that also contains the added item.

Third, you're also generating a new ID value in a reducer.

None of those follow the principle of "pure functions" and immutable updates in reducers.  Since you're directly mutating state and keeping the same array reference, that will almost definitely keep your components from updating properly.

Please see the [Redux FAQ entry on mutations keeping components from rendering](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#react-not-rerendering) for more info, as well as the [Structuring Reducers - Immutable Update Patterns](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html) section.